# Detener un Frame tras abrirse otro Frame

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo un problema a la hora de trabajar con los frames, los cuales no he podido comprender.

Tengo mi funcion main en donde inicio el frame principal, el cual es un Pong. Este frame tiene un JMenuItem el cual le das click y te abre otro Frame, sin embargo el primer frame aun esta activo, y no he comprendido como detenerlo.

```
public class Juegos<bolita> extends javax.swing.JFrame implements KeyListener {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Conectar conectar = new Conectar();
    conectar.consultarTodos();
    Juegos frame = new Juegos();
    while(true){
        frame.moverMundo();
        frame.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(900);
    }
  }

  //La parte donde tengo el JMenuItem para abrir el siguiente frame
  menuVerResultados = new JMenuItem("Ver resultados");
  menuResultado.add(menuVerResultados); 
  
  menuVerResultados.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    @Override public void 
    actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Ver resultados puchado");
            menuResultadoActionPerformed(e);
    }
  });

}
```

Y el Frame que abro `CRUD`

```
public class CRUD extends JFrame{
  public CRUD(){
    this.setTitle("Estadisticas");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(600,600);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Lo primero que intente fue quitar el loop `while` y cambiarlo por `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` sin y solo dejar `moverMundo y repaint()` sin embargo no funciono, algo asi:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Juegos frame = new Juegos();
        frame.moverMundo();
        frame.repaint();
    }
});
```

¿Alguna manera de evitar que se siga ejecutando el primer frame despues de aparecer el segundo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas una clase que funja como controlador; y pudiera servirte que escuche eventos de visibilidad del frame mediante `ComponentListener` ó `WindowListener`.

En este ejemplo, tenemos dos frames: Uno con un botón que cambia su etiqueta constantemente (`Frame1`) y otro con sólo una etiqueta (`Frame2`).

El cambio de etiqueta en `Frame1` se hace con un temporizador, también enviando mensajes a la consola.

Al presionar el botón, detenemos el temporizador y ocultamos `Frame1`,
notificándose automáticamente al controlador (la clase `Frames`) mediante el evento correspondiente.

Dentro del manejo del evento es donde mostramos `Frame2`, observando que los mensajes a la consola del temporizador de `Frame1` se han detenido.

```
public class Frames implements ComponentListener{
   
   JFrame f1 = new Frame1();
   JFrame f2 = new Frame2();
   
   public Frames(){
      f1.setVisible(true);
      f1.addComponentListener(this);      
      
      f2.setVisible(false);
      f2.addComponentListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e){
      System.out.println("componentHidden "+e.getComponent());
      if(e.getComponent()==this.f1)
         f2.setVisible(true);
   }   
   
   public static void main(String[] args){
      new Frames();
   }
   

   public static class Frame1 extends JFrame{
      
      private final JButton btn = new JButton("...");
      String[] s = new String[]{"|","/","-","\\"};
      int i = 0;      
      
      public Frame1(){
         this.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 100);
                  
         Timer t = new Timer();
         t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask(){
               @Override
               public void run(){
                  if( ++i==s.length )
                     i = 0;                     
                  btn.setText(s[i]);
                  System.out.println(">"+i);
               }
            }
         , 3000
         , 500
         );
         
         btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               System.out.println("btn "+e.getActionCommand());
               Frame1.this.setVisible(false);
               t.cancel();
            }
         });
         this.add(btn);

      }      
   }
   
   public static class Frame2 extends JFrame{
      
      public Frame2(){
         this.setBounds(110, 110, 300, 100);
         this.add(new JLabel("Frame2"));
      }
      
   }
   
}
```

El temporizador (clase `Timer`) es para programar la ejecución futura de cierto código -declarado en una `TimerTask`-, con la posibilidad de repetirse en un intervalo determinado. En el ejemplo se programa la ejecución para después de haber transcurrido 3000 milisegundos (3 segundos), y se repite cada 500 milisegundos (medio segundo).

Comment: Gracias :) Tu ejemplo me funciono como guia para otro proyecto que tengo Java... Una pregunta, ¿Para que se utiliza la clase `Timer`. Lei en la doc de oracle pero, no me quedo del todo claro.

Comment: Agregué un párrafo a la respuesta. También dale un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453765) donde explico porqué utilizarlo, considerando que `TimerTask` es precisamente un `Runnable`; aunque la otra pregunta es para JavaFX, la idea también aplica para Swing.