# progressbar javafx no actualiza en un for de manera directa

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Estoy usando netbeans para JavaFX, con jdk 1.8 por medio de Scene Builder, y tengo que actualizar un progressBar.

Tengo una duda respecto al por que de su funcionamiento.
Si utilizo un ciclo for normal para setear sus valores, este no me los setea, si no hasta el final.
Es decir gráficamente no veo el cambio si no hasta el final.
pero cuando lo coloco dentro de un hilo, ahora si me funciona y veo el cambio a medida que el for avanza.
mi pregunta es por que se debe esto? quisiera entender mas el funcionamiento de estos objetos, ya que mas adelante tendré cosas mas complejas, y para mi es importante, entender su funcionamiento basico para poder actuar bien frente a casos que se me presenten a futuro.

yo hago el llamado al progressbar, de esta manera:

```
@FXML
private ProgressBar barra;
```

Luego en un metodo, hago lo siguiente:

```
Thread th = new Thread(new bg_hilo());
            th.start();
```

y este es mi hilo.

```
 class bg_hilo implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {                                    
                barra.setProgress(i/10.0);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(CandadoController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Hasta este punto, funciona muy bien, graficamente, yo veo que la barra de progreso aumenta cada vez.

ya que el for, setea mi barra en 0.1, luego lo setea en 0.2, luego lo setea en 0.3, etc, hasta 1 que seria el 100%, todo perfecto.

Ahora si yo utilizo el .setProgress de manera directa en el for. este no me funciona.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                barra.setProgress(i/10.0);
                System.out.println(i);
            }
```

utilizo el printLn para ver que tan rapido imprime el i, podria ser que pase muy rapido, pero no, no es el caso, yo veo que el i imprime a una velocidad que yo puedo apreciar tranquilamente, pero la barra de manera grafica no cambia, si no hasta el final. cuando el hace la division 10/10 = 1, la barra pinta 100%.
alguien sabe por que? muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las actualizaciones a la Interfaz de Usuario (IU) se manejan exclusivamente en un hilo determinado: el Hilo de Aplicación JavaFX; si saturamos dicho hilo con cómputo no relacionado con la IU parecerá que la aplicación no responde al entorpecer el procesamiento de eventos del usuario como el movimiento del apuntador.
Es por eso que preferimos hacer cómputos tardados en hilos distintos al de la IU, normalmente con alguna implementación de `javafx.concurrent.Worker`. Lo puedes hacer también con una implementación de `Runnable` pero `Worker` maneja una mejor comunicación con el Hilo de Aplicación JavaFX.

- Cuando haces `Thread.sleep()` dentro de un `Runnable` detienes la ejecución de un hilo distinto al de la UI, permitiendo la actualización de la UI.

Por el contrario,

- Cuando haces `Thread.sleep()` dentro del mismo hilo de UI, detienes la actualización de la UI hasta la siguiente oportunidad, que sería cuando termine el `for`.